# Manipulating output from tee to get both data and filename to write to

Tags: bash, pipe, tee

So, I have a situation where I'm grepping out some data, piping it through some other stuff, and outputting to a file.

In the middle of this, I want to output to another file, where both the filename to be written to and the data to write are specified in the line I've just grepped (colon delimited).

The file records are in this format:

```
<filename>:<filedata>
```

The grep (simplified a bit as there's some other stuff that's not relevant to this question) is this:

```
grep -EHv '^ *$' del_[0-9]* 2>/dev/null | sed 's/^del_//' \
                   | ([[ <condition> -eq <true> ]] && (tee --something or other --)) \
                   | cut -d: -f2 \
                   | sort -u > delcache
```

What I want is to append  to  where I have the tee (i.e. before I cut out the second field to output to the final file.

Sample input files:

```
[mike]$ more del_*
::::::::::::::
del_101241_CUSTCARE
::::::::::::::
A-6000021XXX
A-6000002XXX
A-6000021XXX
A-6000021XXX
::::::::::::::
del_111231_ADRCHNG
::::::::::::::
O-7005084XXX
A-2717287XXX
::::::::::::::
del_162915_SRVR.MD
::::::::::::::
O-7811283XXX
A-3619203XXX
O-6311212XXX
A-4203831XXX
::::::::::::::
del_162975_SRVR.NP
::::::::::::::
A-3617332XXX
```

Output from the extra tee statment would be files named upd_* instead of del_* with the same content (In actual fact, it's different values that hold file paths matched from another file by that point, but I've stripped out some of the statement for simplification), and the string that the tee will process in the example here, for the final record in the list above would be

```
162975_SRVR.NP:A-3617332XXX
```

That then should append the value "A-3617332XXX" to the file upd_162975_SRVR.NP

Comment: Can you give us some sample input and output?

Comment: Rather than stating why your attempt failed, spend some time on explaining your requirement. I am sure, there are far simpler ways to use your `grep`, `sed` , `cut` to simpler commands

Comment: I've updated the question with an example.

Answer (score 0):

filtering is done in subprocess

```
$ cat <<END | tee >(
    grep file1 | cut -d: -f2- >out1.txt
)
file1:data1
file2:data2
END

$ cat out1.txt
data1
```

see Process Substitution for more information the `>(command)` or `<(command)` is treated as a filename argument of enclosing command.

EDIT: following comment, the pipelines are a bad design here because each file has to be processed.

Another method.

```
for file in del_[0-9]*; do
    [[ -e $file ]] || continue
    grep -Ev '^ *$' "$file" | tee "upd_${file#del_}"
done |
    sort -u > delcache
```

`-H` grep option removed because each file is treated in loop

`| cut -d: -f2` no more need

Comment: Hi Nahuel. 

The output from that example that I want is 2 files, file1 and file2. 

file1 contains "data1". 

file2 contains "data 2". 

There's no END marker either, just data rows.

Comment: The command is just an example which should be adapted the interesting part is `| tee >(.. >outputfile)`

Comment: How would I tee the second field only from the current value at that point in the pipe into the output file defined by the first field from the current value at that point in the pipe? (See the end of my amended question above for a specific example)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!